# Only include in where condition if value is not null in Linq

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a long sql in which there are multiple where conditions. I want one where condition to only be considered if the value passed is not null

Linq

```
from b in _context.customer
           join d in _context.Address on b.id equals d.Id 
           join e in _context.units on d.Id equals e.Id
           where e.unitNumber == valueProvided)

select new modelAddress
              {
               address= address
              }
```

value provided can be null so I want the where condition to not take e.unitNumber into account. Also this is just an example, actual query is really large

Comment: Robert's answer is the correct one. You may not like it, but by extracting the conditional application so the check is done before a condition is passed to the SQL ensures an optimum query. The alternative is adding conditions like `where e.unitNumber = (valueProvided != null ? valueProvided : e.UnitNumber)` for every nullable condition. This passes these conditions to the SQL to work out, slowing down your query.  Down-voting answer attempts simply because you don't agree with them is pretty poor form.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding well what you want to do, I think that you can validate that property after you do the Linq operation, right?

If not, you can do something like this:

```
from b in _context.customer
           join d in _context.Address on b.id equals d.Id 
           join e in _context.units on d.Id equals e.Id
           where valueProvided.HasValue && e.unitNumber == valueProvided)

select new modelAddress
{
   address= address
}
```

Do you need to use that Linq ou can you use Linq to SQL?

Because with link to SQL you can use the following code:

```
list.Where(w => w.value != null).Where(anotherPredicate);
```

Or

```
list.Where(w => w.value.HasValue && anotherPredicate);
```

Or

```
list.FindAll(f => f.HasValue).Where(wherePredicate);
```

Comment: Has to use that linq

Answer (score 0):

Do your base query (this looks like these should really be navigation properties):

```
var result = from b in _context.customer
       join d in _context.Address on b.id equals d.Id 
       join e in _context.units on d.Id equals e.Id
```

Add in your criteria filters:

```
if (valueProvided != null)
    result = result.Where(e=>e.unitNumber == valueProvided);
if (valueProvided2 != null)
    result = result.Where(e=>e.somethingelse = valueProvided2);
...
```

Add in your pagination (if any):

```
result = result.Skip(pagesize * (currentPage-1)).Take(pagesize);
```

Do your projection:

```
var final = result.Select(r=>new modelAddress
          {
           address= r.address
          });
```

Comment: Just told you that it is huge query, do not want to include if conditions, it is not just one where condition

Comment: So you are saying that for some reason you can't add all your where conditions in the base query above, and then only include the one if condition?  You can of course just use the equivalent of `WHERE (valueProvided == null || e.unitNumber == valueProvided)`, but your performance may take a hit, it isn't very scalable, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: WHERE (valueProvided == null) will not work but valueProvided is not null in database . i just want to exclude it from the query

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your all query and why do you need to filter like that. However I advice a method for it.

```
var filters = new List<Func<Customer, bool>>();
if (valueProvided != null) {
    filters.Add(a => a.unitNumber == valueProvided );
}

var filteredResult = new List<Customer>();
if (filters.Count == 0) {
    filteredResult = _context.customer.Select(s=>new modelAddress{ address=s.address }).ToList();
} else if (filters.Count == 1) {
    filteredResult = _context.customer.Where(filters[0]).Select(s=>new modelAddress{ address=s.address }).ToList();
} else {
    Func<Customer, bool> predicate = filters[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < filters.Count; i++) {
        //I use 'and' here but if you want to use 'or', it is also ok.
        predicate = customer=> predicate(customer) && filters[i](customer);
    }
    filteredResult = _context.customer.Where(predicate).Select(s=>new modelAddress{ address=s.address }).ToList();
}
```

I convert this code block from my context and work well. I see on sql profiller only what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you go by traditional query approach you will find the limitation in clauses that you can apply depending on the value you received,  I would suggest to use dynamic linq expression binding.

You can check this blog for further details .
http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx/

I would recommend not go with traditional if else or switch case as this will increases complexity as system grows

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody looking for this, not really bothered of performance.

```
from b in _context.customer
           join d in _context.Address on b.id equals d.Id 
           join e in _context.units on d.Id equals e.Id
           where ((valueProvided != null && e.unitNumber == valueProvided ) ||
                 (valueProvided == null && e.unitNumber != valueProvided))
```

Works just fine for simple scenarios where valueProvided is nullable.